# Auth::attempt value always false

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I have some problem when I want to make login, I got an issue for my `Auth::attempt` always false value, Is am I got something wrong in my code?

Controller :

```
public function register(Request $register)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($register->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 401);
    } else {
        $name = $register->input('name');
        $email = $register->input('email');
        $pwd = $register->input('password');
        $c_pwd = $register->input('c_password');

        // Crypting password & c_password to md5
        $md5_pwd = md5($pwd);
        $md5_c_pwd = md5($c_pwd);

        // Salt password & c_password 
        $password = crypt($md5_pwd, "asd");
        $c_password = crypt($md5_c_pwd, "asd");

        $data = new User();

        if ($password == $c_password) {
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $name,
                'email' => $email,
                'password' => $password,
            ]);
            $success['token'] = $user->createToken('SSOApp')->accessToken;
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'token' => $success,
                'user' => $user
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => "Password doesn't match"], 401);
        }
    }
}

public function login()
{
    $email = request('email');
    $pwd = request('password');
    $md5 = md5($pwd);
    $password = crypt($md5, "asd");
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] = $user->createToken('SSOApp')->accessToken;
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'token' => $success,
            'user' => $user
        ]);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Invalid Email or Password',
        ], 401);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using md5() over bcrypt() is not recommended. and Auth::attempt use bcrypt for check user password.

Comment: so what I must do for using method for my md5() and bcrypt()?

Comment: Don't use your own encryption if possible. Use laravel default bcrypt() by calling Hash::make('string') while saving the user password.

Comment: so just use an defult method using bcrypt? Cannot using another method?

Comment: You can use other drivers "bcrypt", "argon", "argon2id" for hashing by specifying the driver inside config/hash.php file as They are currently supported these 3 drivers. So if you want to use the laravel default auth system then go one of them otherwise create your own auth system(md5, or whatever you want)

Comment: Ok thanks for your suggest I will try your method in another time, because I just wanna learn laravel carefully, I'm so confused Laravel is not easy enough compare in CI...hehehe

Comment: It looks like difficult but actually it is very easy. Laravel using very clear, concise code with migration, validation features that do not exist in CI.  That is out of scope comment. hihihi. Good luck with laravel.

Comment: Yes you're right laravel it's very clear, but I want have many time learn more this framework, Thank You bro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you messed up with Laravel Default Password Hashing System

```
public function register(Request $register)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($register->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 401);
    } else {
        $name = $register->input('name');
        $email = $register->input('email');
        $pwd = $register->input('password');
        $c_pwd = $register->input('c_password');


        // $data = new User();

        $user = User::create([
                'name' => $name,
                'email' => $email,
                'password' => bcrypt($password . 'salt'),
        ]);

        $success['token'] = $user->createToken('SSOApp')->accessToken;
        return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'token' => $success,
                'user' => $user
        ]);

    }
}

public function login()
{
    $email = request('email');
    $pwd = request('password');

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password . 'salt'])) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] = $user->createToken('SSOApp')->accessToken;
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'token' => $success,
            'user' => $user
        ]);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Invalid Email or Password',
        ], 401);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok That is work but I have some question, if I using `crypt($password, "salt")` and `bcrypt($password . "salt")` is different method?

Comment: Short answer : yes.
However, I cna't find any references in the doc for `crypt` usage in Laravel

Comment: haha oke thanks that enough, because I migrate from CI to Laravel, I thought laravel have an crypt like in CI but different framework have different method

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I don't know what happened to your code about the password you tried  to encrypt it in `attempt`.

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request) {
      if(!Auth::attempt([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'active' => true
      ])) {
        return response()->json('Email or Password is incorrect', 500);
      }

      $this->user = Auth::user()->load('roles');
      return $this->createUserAccessTokenResponse();
    }

protected function createUserAccessTokenResponse() {
      return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'data' => [
          'token' => $this->user->createToken($this->user->name)->accessToken,
          'user' => $this->user
        ],
      ], 200);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that laravel by default hashes the password. so when you do `Auth::attempt` it's going to hash the password you provided. And the result is what you get, it will always false.

Instead, you need to [Other Authentication Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#other-authentication-methods).

```php
Auth::login($user);

// Login and "remember" the given user...
Auth::login($user, true);
```

Above is the easiest way to fix your code.

It's recommended to hash your password rather than encrypting the password.

Hashing password in laravel is also

```php
Hash::make($password);
```

And then you can use `Auth::attempt` to log in your user.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `md5` or `crypt` use `\Hash::make()` it is much secure
I refactored your code and it does the same thing
You only need to rename your `c_password` to `password_confirmation`
[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-confirmed)
Below code does the same thing that your code do

```php
public function register(Request $register)
{
    $this->validate($register, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $register->input('name'),
        'email' => $register->input('email'),
        'password' => $register->input('password'),
    ]);
    $success['token'] = $user->createToken('SSOApp')->accessToken;

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'token' => $success,
        'user' => $user,
    ]);
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->merge(['password' => \Hash::make($request->input('password'))]);

    if (Auth::attempt($request->only(['email', 'password']))) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] = $user->createToken('SSOApp')->accessToken;

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'token' => $success,
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Invalid Email or Password',
    ], 401);
}
```

when you hashing password using `crypt` it has a key to unlock it that's why there is a `decrypt` but when you use `Hash::make()` it doesn't have a key to break or unlock it, it will check it's algorithm to see if given password is matching the algorithm that already exists in the database that's why `crypt` is not safe and Hash::make is much much more safe

Comment: It's not different when I just using default bcrypt? And then in register function where the `bcrypt` for crypt the password?

Comment: I updated my answer and described why hash::make is better

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Auth uses the  bcrypt hashing when saving password via model you may use either of the 2 method

`$account->password = bcrypt("YOUR_PASSWORD");`  or `$account->password = Hash::make("YOUR_PASSWORD");`

Then if  you're dealing with the auth attempt function, just simply call  the method  like this

```
if($account = Auth::attemp(['email' => "YOUR_EMAIL@DOMAIN.COM",  'password' => "YOUR_PASSWORD"])){
    //success login, do your extra job here
}else{
    //invalid credentials here
}
```